# Simple moving average using recursion

Tags: c, average

I'm trying to find the average of a series of numbers:

```
double moving_average((unsigned num )
{
    double temp;

    temp = calculate_number(num);

    if ( num > 0 ) moving_average( num - 1 );
    else
      return 0;
    return temp * (n - 1) / num;
}
```

I'm trying to implement indicating this page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

but this code I did does not return me the correct average ¿what is the problem with implementation?

Comment: Does it even compile?

Comment: Hmm, average is the total divided by the number of elements, so you  keep track of your total and number of elements and your moving total is always total/n, otherwise you have to unnecessarily weight things.

Answer (score 8):

The main defect in your program is that the recursive calculation is incorrect.

To calculate the average, you have to get the **sum of the current value and the remaining values**, then divide that sum by the **number of values**.

- The **number of values** is `num`.
- The **current value** is whatever `calculate_number()` returns.
- The **sum of the remaining values** is `num-1` multiplied by **the average of the remaining values**.
- The **average of the remaining values** is calculated by making a recursive call to `average()`.

Thus, we write the following:

```
double average(int num) {
    double current = calculate_number(num);
    if (num == 1) {
        return current;
    }
    return (current + (num-1)*average(num-1)) / num;
}
```

A complete program using that function might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr_length = 16;
double arr[] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9, 3};

double calculate_number(int i) {
    return arr[arr_length-i];
}

double average(int num) {
    double current = calculate_number(num);
    if (num == 1) {
        return current;
    }
    return (current + (num-1)*average(num-1)) / num;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
        printf("average of the last %d numbers = %.3f\n",
                i, average(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this isn't a very good way to calculate the average because you lose precision every time you divide the current sum by `num`. When this average gets multiplied again as the recursive call returns, the significant digits that you lost in the division do not get restored. You are destroying information by dividing and then multiplying the sum. For greater precision, you would want to keep track of the sum as you go through the elements, then divide at the end.

Another point to consider is what is meant by a moving average. What we've implemented above is not a moving average but a fixed average. It is the average of a fixed window of elements. If you move the window by one position, you have to start all over and compute the sum again.

The proper way to implement a moving window is to keep track of all the elements in the window. When you shift the window one position to the right, you remove the leftmost element from the window and subtract its value from the sum, then add the new rightmost element to the window and add its value to the sum. That's what makes it a moving sum. Dividing the moving sum by the number of elements gives you the moving average.

The natural way to implement a moving window is with a queue because you can add new elements to the head and pop old elements from the tail.

Comment: "The proper way to implement a moving window is to keep track of all the elements in the window. When you shift the window one position to the right, you remove the leftmost element from the window and subtract its value from the sum" as would be this interested me much and many thanks